# How would I install Sonar in my existing Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I would like to integrate Sonar Qube in my Existing Jenkins Set Up(Build Script in ANT).Please do help me in doing it

Mike

Comment: please show us what you tried to do and where you failed

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and recommended way would be to use [SonarQube Jenkins Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341). The documentation explains the process quite nicely and there is an option to run Standalone analysis, which is not dependent on your build process...